# Connection between the akeidah and bikkurim

Tags: sources-mekorot, avot-patriarch-fathers, binding-of-isaac, bikkurim-first-fruits

Some of the akeidah selichos, particularly for days 4 and 5 of teshuvah (Artscroll Minhag Lita), contain references to the mitzvah of bikkurim.  Are there any other sources that draw this comparison and flesh it out a bit more?

I would guess that the basis of the comparison is that bikkurim are [called a korban](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.2.12?p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.2.12.1) and brought to (but not on) the mizbeyach, but then they go to the Kohanim and [become their property](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bikkurim.3.12), like terumah with some of the restrictions of maaser sheni.  Similarly, Yitzchak was brought to the mizbeach but not offered on it and went on to live a mostly normal life, with some restrictions.

Comment: Yitzchak was also treated as the *bekhor*.